# Blackberry "There is no connected BlackBerry device." when trying to debug

Tags: debugging, blackberry, device

I am trying to test my app on a Blackberry Bold 9900 but Eclipse can not seem to find the device. I have installed the signatures, Windows drivers for Blackberry and the Blackberry desktop software.

When trying to debug I rightclick I choose Debug as -> Blackberry Device.
It then checks all the signatures and everything is fine, then an error pops up saying "There is no connected BlackBerry device.", eventhough Windows finds the device in explorer.

Have I missed something?

Someone?

Comment: connect your device with datacable first and restart your system and run the Eclipse; In Debug as-->BlackberryDevice--> click on refresh; you can get it;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the exact same [Bold 9900 simulator](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/resources/simulators.jsp) version installed as your real 9900 device. The debugger needs the simulator debug libraries to be able to debug a real device.

Comment: ok thanks, Ill look into this more. I can't seem to install new simulators though but I guess that is another question. Also I can not find a simulator that has the exact same release as my phone.

Comment: Download a generic simulator for your blackberry model and OS. This won't include the debug files for any carrier specific applications on your real device (which will generate a warning when you start the debugger) but that's OK because you're not trying to debug those applications.

Comment: I have the 9900 device with v7.0.0.585 .. should it work with 7.0.0.540 simulator? Still can't get it running..

Comment: Eclipse says "No debug information found at 'net_rim_cldc'. Please ensure that you have installed the simulator package that matches the handheld code you are attempting to debug."

Comment: That's OK, just check the box to ignore those warnings and the debugger should still run.

Answer (score 2):

Try reinstalling the Blackberry desktop software. It should work.